# How to save encryption key in registry in CryptoAPI?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, aes, cryptoapi

I am new to MFC and CryptoAPI. I want to encrypt trace files in my application.
The key derived successfully using a password and I am able to encrypt the data. The encrypted data written in a file. While opening the file again the key becomes 0 since I haven't stored it anywhere.

I am planning to store the key generated to the registry.

```
bool CCrypto::DeriveKey(CString strPassword)
{
    //  Return failure if we don't have a context or hash.
    if(m_hCryptProv == NULL || m_hHash == NULL)
        return false;

    //  If we already have a hash, trash it.
    if(m_hHash)
    {
        CryptDestroyHash(m_hHash);
        m_hHash = NULL;
        if(!CryptCreateHash(m_hCryptProv, CALG_MD5, 0, 0, &m_hHash)) 
            return false;
    }

    //  If we already have a key, destroy it.
    if(m_hKey)
    {
        ::CryptDestroyKey(m_hKey);
        m_hKey = NULL;
    }

    //  Hash the password. This will have a different result in UNICODE mode, as it
    //  will hash the UNICODE string (this is by design, allowing for UNICODE passwords, but
    //  it's important to be aware of this behaviour.
    if(!CryptHashData(m_hHash, (const BYTE*)(LPCSTR)strPassword, strPassword.GetLength() * sizeof(TCHAR), 0)) 
        return false;

    //  Create a session key based on the hash of the password.
    if(!CryptDeriveKey(m_hCryptProv, CALG_RC2, m_hHash, CRYPT_EXPORTABLE, &m_hKey))
        return false;

    HKEY subKey;
    char data[256] = "";
    unsigned long length = 255;
    DWORD disposition;
    char main_key[256] = "Software\\HFS Internal Interface";
    if (RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, main_key, 0, "", REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, &subKey, &disposition) == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        RegSetValueEx(subKey, "Encryption", 0, REG_SZ, (unsigned char *)m_hKey, length);
    }
    //  And we're done.
    return true;
}
```

But when `m_hKey` of type `HCRYPTKEY` gets converted to Unicode characters. I need to store the correct key in registry. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Because you're saving it as a REG_SZ not a REG_BINARY? But you probably need to save the PRIVATEKEYBLOB from CryptExportKey or some other information to reconstruct the key, not just the handle. And why not use the certificate store, why the registry?

Comment: @Rup Thanks for the break through. I hope you meant that there are some functions as you mentioned to store the key.

Comment: @Rup I believe, for a  HCRYPTPROV handle and the HCRYPTHASH value, the  CryptDeriveKey() provides same key always. Am I right?

Comment: I don't know sorry. Skimming [the MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptderivekey), yes that sounds correct, but I can't say for sure.

Comment: @Rup The thing is I am getting different HCRYPTHASH value for encryption and decryption. I suspect that's why my decryption fails due to incorrect key.

Answer (score 0):

you serialize handle to the key, not the key data
probably you should export key after encryption via CryptExportKey
and import it in decryption via CryptImportKey

Moreover, if you derive your key from the hash, why not to store the hash in a registry, and then derive it from this hash again